# cannot display label from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client-side-validation

I am validating a form from javascript. 
**The target is:** if user do not enter value in a required field, an error message will show up and will disappear after few seconds.
BUT
**The problem is:**  The error message don't show up and this is probably because from javascript I am failing to write error message in a label control. BUT, if I use javascript alert instead of displaying the label, it works.

The code:
Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showConfirmation() {
        $('div#confirmationDV').show();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('div#confirmationDV').fadeOut(5000);
        });
    }
    function validateRequiredField() {
        if (document.getElementById("<%=txtOfferTitle.ClientID%>").value == "") {
            alert("error.....");//this alert works.
            document.all("<%=lblConfirmation.ClientID%>").innerHTML = "please enter your business name"; // this does not work
            document.all("<%=lblConfirmation.ClientID%>").style.color = "red";
            showConfirmation();
            document.getElementById("<%=txtOfferTitle.ClientID%>").focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="round-conf-box" id="confirmationDV">
            <div class="round-conf-tl">
                <div class="round-conf-tr"></div>
                <div class="round-conf-background_color_top"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="round-conf-box-Content">
                <asp:Label ID="lblConfirmation" runat="server" CssClass="confirmationLabel"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="round-conf-bl">
                  <div class="round-conf-br"></div>
                  <div class="round-conf-background_color_bottom"></div>
            </div>
```

//...some other stuff

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="iBtnSave" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/createOffer.png"         
onclick="iBtnSave_Click" OnClientClick="return validateRequiredField()" />
```

and in the code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            iBtnSave.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return validateRequiredField()");
//some other stuff
}}
```

Would be nice if anyone can help me to find my mistakes..
cheers

Comment: Is your validation done on the client side or server side? If client side then why do you use the asp tags within validation function?

Comment: it is in client side. inside the validateRequiredField() function. What asp tag you are talking about?

Comment: document.all("<%=lblConfirmation.ClientID%>").innerHTML = "please enter your business name"; // this does not work
document.all("<%=lblConfirmation.ClientID%>").style.color = "red"; these tags will be replaced at server side na? Did you check the values replaced by viewing the source of the page displayed in the browser?

Comment: :)Those lines work dude.'ClientID' replaces with the actual ID of the control. Now I have a twist, The above code works on Chrome and IE but not in firefox. :)

Answer (score 1):

You mix jQuery and IE-Only JScript.

Make sure to only use jQuery or cross browser JavaScript

Change

```
function validateRequiredField() {
        if (document.getElementById("<%=txtOfferTitle.ClientID%>").value == "") {
            alert("error.....");
            document.all("<%=lblConfirmation.ClientID%>").innerHTML = "please enter your business name";
            document.all("<%=lblConfirmation.ClientID%>").style.color = "red";
            showConfirmation();
            document.getElementById("<%=txtOfferTitle.ClientID%>").focus();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

to

```
$("#<%=iBtnSave.ClientID%>).click(function(e) {
  var txtOffer = $("#<%=txtOfferTitle.ClientID%>");
  var txtOfferLbl = $("#<%=lblConfirmation.ClientID%>");
  if (txtOffer.val() == "") {
    alert("error.....");
    txtOfferLbl.text("please enter your business name");
    txtOfferLbl.addClass("error");
    showConfirmation();
    txtOffer.focus();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else {
    txtOfferLbl.text("");
    txtOfferLbl.removeClass("error");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But It is not working. Do I need to add anything on the page_load event?? Just for your info, My code is working in Chrome and IE but it is not working in Firefox. Any further help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Without looking at the actual page and its rendered output, I cannot guarantee my code is working since I have assumed quite a few things.
For example you need a style: `.error { color:red }`

Comment: @kandroid Could you return to comment on my concerns?